# Kill doubles within one line, from CSV file

Tags: regex, perl, sqlite, csv, awk

Input file is from group_concatenated SQL query output, where there were some duplicate values. It is already used with DISTINCT, but it was not enough, as only some substrings were identical.

So, the column I'm interested in is the 9th column.
The idea is, to print on one line only non-duplicate IAB categories.

Sample from that file:

```
148422,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000165021,wpolityce.pl,300x250,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB17;IAB12;IAB9;IAB15;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB17;IAB12;IAB9;IAB13;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB12;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,728x90,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB12;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,750x100,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB12;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,750x200,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB12;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,750x300,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23,IAB3;IAB11;IAB12;IAB9"
```

I want to delete duplicate IAB categories, so for the first line it would go like this:

```
148422,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000165021,wpolityce.pl,300x250,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB17;IAB12;IAB9;IAB15;IAB23;IAB13;IAB23"
```

In my SQL query, I have something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT foo) FROM t;
```

Now the foo-column can contain values along of these lines:

```
foo
bar
qrr
foo;bar
foo;qrr
foo
foo;qrr
bar
qrr
foo
```

Concatenating those values using `DISTINCT` will remove all direct duplicates. Split up, that's as follows:

```
foo
bar
qrr
foo;bar
foo;qrr
```

I am interested in *individual values* (`foo`, `bar` and `qrr`). If the delimiter used to concat is `;` it will appear as if not all duplicates have been removed.

The final output in that column after it has been concatenated with `;` should be:

```
foo;bar;baz
```

**How do I remove those duplicates?**

I tried to do it, but alas I'm not that advanced in AWK etc.

I'm working with Bash, although I can do it also "one step earlier", in SQLite.

Comment: 9th row? Do you mean 9th column?

Comment: @JMKS: please post your code ?

Comment: Why didn't you just `group_concat(distinct foo)` in your SQL query?

Comment: @JamesBrown of course column, edited.

Comment: @simbabque I have done that, for some lines it was enough; others were not identical, but close - so it concatenated (those are separated by a comma within 9th column).

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you have `IAB3;` and `IAB3,`? Which delimiter do you keep? Is it safe to convert all to semicolons?  A solution can't avoid addressing that question.

Comment: @DavidO it is not essential for me; but let's keep it separated by ";" as the separator within those values.

Comment: So basically, for some of the lines that were grouped, the value that went into the `group_concat` was `foo`, for some it was `bar`, but for some it was `foo;bar`. And that's why those were not already filtered out. From those three cases, you want your output to be only `foo;bar`. Is that correct?

Comment: @simbabque Yes, something like that, but the possibilities are more mixed, it could be "1;2;3", "1;3;4" and "5;7;9", from which I would like to get "1;2;3;4;5;7;9".

Comment: @JMKS I edited that into your question for you. I hope you don't mind. It can be done in Perl, though not really as a one-liner.

Comment: Do you REALLY sometimes have commas and sometimes have semi-colons between the IAB values (`...IAB13;IAB23,IAB3...`)?

Comment: It was a design choice (flaw?) before. I had some semi-preparated data, from which I preparated data to inject into SQLite. For it to properly import, I separated it with semicolons (to import into one cell, to preserve fixed column number). And in fact during group_concat I could have used semicolon as a separator; yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the column to be processed is always the only one in double quotes, and it is okay to replace all separators with semicolons, this will do as you ask

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'uniq';

while ( <> ) {
    s{ " ([^"]+) " }{ '"' . join(';', uniq $1 =~ /\w+/g) . '"' }ex;
    print;
}
```

#### output

```
148422,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000165021,wpolityce.pl,300x250,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB17;IAB12;IAB9;IAB15;IAB23;IAB13"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,728x90,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,750x100,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,750x200,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,750x300,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23;IAB9"
```

Comment: It should be fine.
Very basic question - where input file goes?
As I understand, it is a Bash script, but not all is clear to me (I use cygwin, and can use native Linux also, if necessary).

Comment: @JMKS: You need to put the above code into, for instance, `script.pl` and then run `perl script.pl my_input_file.txt`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :)
I was only using perl one-liners before, so I was a little confused.

Comment: @JMKS: Yes, I didn't want to risk offering you a one-liner because of all those quotes to escape, as I don't have a Linux platform to test with at present.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ awk -F\" '{split($2,a,"[,;]"); for(i in a) b[a[i]]; $2=""; for(i in b) $2=$2($2=="" ? "" : ";")""i} 1' file
148422,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000165021,wpolityce.pl,300x250,standard,3, IAB11;IAB12;IAB3;IAB13;IAB23;IAB15;IAB17;IAB9

BEGIN {
    FS="\""                         # field separate at "
}
{
    split($2,a,"[,;]")              # split from "," and ";"
    delete b                        # reset b
    for(i in a) 
        b[a[i]]                     # pick unique strings from a
    $2=""                           # reset $2 for ternary operator below
    for(i in b) 
        $2=$2($2=="" ? "" : ";")""i # rebuild $2 from i ";" delimiting
} 
1
```

Comment: I don't know what it exactly does, but definitely not what I was looking for - it truncated my file from ~1800 lines to ~50 lines.

Comment: There goes the only copy... :D

Comment: @JMKS that is not possible. The `1` at the end means the script prints each line that is read in (after modification), it **will not** delete lines, nor will it have any effect on the original file.

Comment: Of course it has not messed with my original file, as it was not in-place edit (I did not lost any data, it was simply stating the fact that it was completely different from what I expected); but the result had 50 lines, compared to 1800 in original file. And the solution you posted originally was way different than it appears today (first of all, it was one line only, without explanation), so I don't exactly know what this one does.
I tested it briefly now, and I'm not sure, as after the Perl solution, I'm not that interested anymore, but current solution is probably correct too.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" }
{
    split($2,iabs,/[,;]/)
    tmp = ""
    delete seen
    for (i=1;i in iabs;i++) {
        if (!seen[iabs[i]]++) {
            tmp = (tmp ? "" : tmp ";") iabs[i]
        }
    }
    $2 = tmp
}
1
' file
148422,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000165021,wpolityce.pl,300x250,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB17;IAB12;IAB9;IAB15;IAB23;IAB13"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,728x90,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,750x100,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,750x200,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23;IAB9"
118243,0.72499999999999998,0.72499999999999998,0.72500000000058573,wpolityce.pl,750x300,standard,3,"IAB3;IAB11;IAB1;IAB12;IAB13;IAB23;IAB9"
```

Comment: Dear drive-by downvoter - care to explain why the downvote?